# Python List generation: Force new Object

Tags: python, list

Is there a way in Python to force to generate a new object when creating a list?

Assume I have a class `Test` of which I want to store 5 objects in a list.
I use the following code to generate the list:

```
myList = [Test()] * 5
```

With this code python creates only 1 Object which is stored 5 times.

Of course I could use a for-loop to generate the list. But in my real program this would blow up the code extremly, because I have about 30 lists, which are partly nested in another List.

So Is there a fast way (maybe a one-liner) to force python to generate a new Object in each entry?

Comment: `[Test() for i in range(5)]`?

Comment: Shouldn't you use the "new" keyword ?

Comment: @vekah: wrong language.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and even still they shouldn't use `new` they should prefer RAII `std::vector<Test> myList(5)` :)

Comment: @Cyber Not if he is using Java :D

Comment: `map(lambda obj: Test(), xrange(5))` built-in `map` function can be used.

Comment: @TanveerAlam: and in Python 3 that'll produce an iterator, not a list.

Comment: @TanveerAlam, in this case, underscore may be used as lambda variable specifier too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to execute an expression more than once:

```
myList = [Test() for _ in range(5)]
```

Since this would ignore the `range()`-produced index, I named the `for` loop target `_` to [signal the variable is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python); this is just a naming convention.

Comment: Thank you! this works. For my nested list I can use `myList = [[Test() for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(2)]`  What exaclty means the `_` , by the way?

Comment: @0xAffe It is an informal way to say "I am not going to use this variable" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python

Comment: @0xAffe: it is just convention, just like naming the first argument of a method `self`.

Comment: @0xAffe, in some IDEs, it will save you from warnings about unused variables